# TYPO3 TCA Fields order in Backend

Tags: php, typo3

Is there a possibility to change the fields order in the backend?
[image]

Example Photo:
First the field -> Publish date month (on top)
Second Field -> Creation date

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The order of the fields depends on the order of the fields and palettes in the `showItem` and palettes definition.

The exact syntax of these entries can be found in the [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/10.4/en-us/Types/Index.html#showitem)